# ng-grid custom filtering in sub-header row

Tags: angular-ui, ng-grid

I just found [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) and would like to use it for a server-side filtered and ordered table, which shouldn't be a problem.

But I'd like to define the filtering in cells that are in the next row under the header row. Filtering cells could be:

- text search
- date range
- number range
- enum multi-select
- ...?

I've not found, how I could add an extra row under the header row. I could 
overwrite the header cell templates, but I'm fine with them. I'd rather 
"extend" them or have a plugin that would be responsible to render the row 
under the header row.

Is there a way to refer to the original template when defining 
headerCellTemplate? I just want to add something to the existing template.

Do you have more infos on plugins, their capabilities and how to write them?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement. Since our column defs were all dynamically driven, we also included an attribute called inputMappings. Which contained the input type, select options, etc. Then wrote an ng-grid plugin which added a watch to that scope variable, parsed the colDefs variable - creating an row by extracting the elements from our inputMapping object. Basically the "field_name" was the linkage between inputMapping and colDefs.

Once we had the row comprised of ngCells, that contained the proper input element, contained ng-models linked to the fields, we insterted after the gird.$headercontainer and recompiled ng-grid. This added the UI. Our next challenge was writing a custom ng-grid server-side filter to leverage the nifty new "ngFilterBar".